export pages form to pdf and include select value
I am working with Angular 17 and firebase, and I have a form report that the client wants to export to PDF. The problem is that I have some select elements on my pages, and when I convert it, it is not taking the selected value but the default value (as if it is not set already).
I have tried a lot of things, but nothing works. Thank you for your help.
And just in case, I have already been advised to use something other than a select, but that is not possible because I have other selects in the form with many possible choices (+30).
P.S.: The code base is not mine. I just got the project after a colleague left.
Thank you in advance for your help.
The code ts :
 async sendFormAndEmail() {
    try {
      this.isSubmitted = 'inprogress';
      const pdf = await this.generatePDF();
      pdf.save('yoyo.pdf');
      return;
    }
 }

async generatePDF() {
    let data = this.pdfPage.nativeElement.cloneNode(true);
    document.body.appendChild(data);
    data.classList.add('pdf');
    let allData = [];

    const boxes = data.getElementsByClassName(
      'pdfpart'
    ) as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLDivElement>;

    Array.from(boxes).forEach((box) => {
      // console.log(box.innerText);
      allData.push(box);
    });

    let pdf = this.addImage(allData);
    return pdf;
  }

async addImage(allData) {
    let pdf: any = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4', true);
    let position = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < allData.length; i++) {
      console.log(position);
      
      const txtareaList = allData[i].querySelectorAll('textarea');
      txtareaList.forEach((t) => {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.textContent = t.value;
        div.classList.add(...t.classList);
        div.classList.add('textarea');
        div.style.height = 'fit-content';
        div.style.whiteSpace = 'pre-wrap';
        t.replaceWith(div);
      });
  
      const selectList = allData[i].querySelectorAll('select');
      console.log(selectList);
      selectList.forEach((s) => {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        const selectedOption = s.options[s.selectedIndex];
        div.textContent = selectedOption ? selectedOption.textContent : '';
        div.classList.add(...s.classList);
        s.replaceWith(div);
      });
      const canvas = await html2canvas(allData[i]);
      let imgWidth = 210;
      let imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width;

      const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 0.01);
      pdf.addImage(
        contentDataURL,
        'PNG',
        0,
        position,
        imgWidth,
        imgHeight,
        '',
        'FAST'
      );
      position += imgHeight;
      if (position > 150) {
        pdf.addPage();
        position = 0;
      }
    }
    return pdf;
  }

htmp part :
<div class="card py-2 m-5 pdfpart">
....
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-6 d-flex align-items-center">
     <label>Genre</label>
    </div>
      <div class="col-6 d-flex align-items-center">
        <select class="form-control" formControlName="gender">
         <option value="" disabled selected>
           Choisir ...
         </option>
         <option>Garçon</option>
         <option>Fille</option>
         </select>
         </div>
    </div>
 </div>
....
 </div>

the Form :
we see the select is have a value 
the PDF :
and here the select is default 
Thank you in advance for your help.
